# SMART test results show "Aborted by host"

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

I have run a long-form SMART test on a disk local to a Linux system,  using the following command:

```
sudo smartctl -t long -d sat /dev/sdc
```

Once I was certain the test completed, I requested a report on the results using the following command:

```
sudo smartctl -a -d sat /dev/sdc
```

The full report is shown below.

I need help interpreting the results, in particular, the recurring instances of the phrase *Aborted by host*, appearing near the end of the report. More generally, what important conclusions may I understand from the report?

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-40-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     HGST HUS726T4TALA6L4
Serial Number:    V1G9RS3C
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 0bcc46cb9
Firmware Version: VLGNW460
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon May 16 13:13:42 2022 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  25) The self-test routine was aborted by
                    the host.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 503) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   130   130   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       100
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   133   133   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       317 (Average 317)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       213
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   128   128   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       550
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       51
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       51
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       21 (Min/Max 17/35)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       213
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       108
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 256 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 256 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 195 hours (8 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 30 90 ce 42 40 08   6d+07:12:00.580  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 80 cf 42 40 08   6d+07:11:58.132  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 20 78 cf 42 40 08   6d+07:11:58.131  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 70 cf 42 40 08   6d+07:11:58.131  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 10 68 cf 42 40 08   6d+07:11:58.131  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 255 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 195 hours (8 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 40 88 90 ce 42 40 08   6d+07:11:56.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 70 30 5f 43 40 08   6d+07:11:56.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 e0 40 50 5c 43 40 08   6d+07:11:54.495  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 f8 38 58 59 43 40 08   6d+07:11:54.491  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 30 18 54 43 40 08   6d+07:11:54.491  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 254 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 195 hours (8 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 40 c8 30 8b 38 40 08   6d+07:11:45.813  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 d8 b0 95 38 40 08   6d+07:11:43.319  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 d0 70 90 38 40 08   6d+07:11:43.319  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 c0 f0 85 38 40 08   6d+07:11:43.319  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 b8 b0 80 38 40 08   6d+07:11:43.319  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 253 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 168 hours (7 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 60 e0 4c 44 40 08   5d+04:30:26.393  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 d0 28 55 22 40 08   5d+04:30:23.408  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 c8 e8 5d b1 40 08   5d+04:30:23.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 c0 78 c6 44 40 08   5d+04:30:23.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 b8 58 c1 44 40 08   5d+04:30:23.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 252 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 168 hours (7 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 40 58 a8 47 44 40 08   5d+04:30:21.872  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 f0 d0 4d 43 40 08   5d+04:30:17.710  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 e8 a0 27 43 40 08   5d+04:30:17.667  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 e0 e0 5f 90 40 08   5d+04:30:17.667  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 d8 e0 df 90 40 08   5d+04:30:17.667  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       526         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       442         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       284         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       254         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       254         -
# 6  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       245         -
# 7  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       243         -
# 8  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       241         -
# 9  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       241         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        52         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        24         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: The abort reason is self explanatory - host cancelled it perhaps by a reboot, sleep, hibernate, shutdown, etc. It's highly unlikely the drive is failing since there are no offline uncorrectable sectors and no errors reported by the self-test, albeit a long test must be run to completion - at least 503min. If you believe the host is not cancelling the test, create a script to execute `smartctl -a /dev/sdc | grep progress >> ~/smart.log` every 15s, and if it doesn't reach completed, check the system log for what occurred when the abort happened. Reallocated sectors likely occured prior to 196hrs

Answer (score 1):

The following attributes indicate that your drive is about to die and that you should replace it. You have a current total of 108 unreadable sectors (probably more). 213 sectors have been replaced by spare sectors.

> Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
> ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED

> 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       213

> 196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       213

> 197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       108

If you don't have a copy of your drive you should consider duplicating it using a fault-tolerant software like ddrescue on linux. Live linux editions like Gparted, System Rescue CD, Knoppix come with ddrescue already built-in.

Somebody or something aborted your extend offline report.
You have a very new hard drive that is showing serious errors and I wonder why. Did you drop it? Did you switch it off while it was still writing?

Running the offline report might have the firmware discover some additional pending (unreadable) sectors but you should really have started with a complete report of your smart parameters.
The report might already have indicated that the drive is about to fail leading you to duplicate the drive instead of running multiple instances of an extended offline test.

Creating a duplicate early would haved stressed your already broken drive less.

Comment: The drive is simply being evaluated for future functionality, so data preservation is not a present consideration. In general, what is the simplest way to interpret the report for understanding the failing state of the device?

Comment: There is no simple way to interpret such as combining every information in just one traffic light in red, yellow or green color as some software does. New drives start with a figure of zero for the three parameters mentioned. Once those parameters start rising above zero I would replace the drive.

Comment: I understand, and yet, for some reason, the report shows the result as *passed*.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I rebooted, closed all programs and disconnect the internet. Then I didn't get any "Aborted by host". If it continues to error you can use fsck utility to check for errors and even fix some issues use (df -h) to help figure out drive.

1. Make sure drive isn't mounted (sudo umount /dev/sdX)
2. Dry run is a good idea (sudo fsck -N /dev/sdX)
3. error check it (sudo fsck /dev/sdX)
4. reboot, umount, and run it agian but auto fix (sudo fsck -y /dev/sdX) or just check for errors without repair (sudo fsck -n /dev/sdX)

Let us know if this helped.

Comment: Did you run the long test after you rebooted, or simply query for the results report?

Comment: Yes, ran Long test.  Ran without 'Aborted by host' after reboot, closing everything, and disconnecting from network.

Comment: So you rebooted first, and then you started the long test again?

Comment: Czar, you missed that the drive in question is broken and requires replacement.

Comment: @Czar Please use correct markdown for monospaced code _(please see formatting bar or help)_

Comment: The original question is about the  reason for the phrase appearing in the report.